# Gsheet Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do a vlookup in Gsheets between two different sheets.  I'm trying to get the importrange function to work correctly first before I add in the vlookup function but can't seem to get it to link.

What am I doing wrong with this function below?

=IMPORTRANGE(“https://gsheet address that I'm trying to link”,"Tab name!A2:X1115")

I've read a bunch of tutorials and believe I have the above correct but I'm still getting '#ERROR!'

Would really appreciate any help!  TY!

Answer (score 1):

*Try changing those slanted/stylized double quotes you are using **`“`** for *sheet address* with regular quotes **`"`** & then test the formula*